# Add a trailing slash on a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm very new with mod_rewrite and I'm trying to get my own rules...
I have this simple line:

```
RewriteRule  ^concorso/(.*)/$    concorso/?iModule=13&iData=$1   [L]
```

It is working with URLs like:
http://www.mysite.com/concorso/2/
but not with URLs like
http://www.mysite.com/concorso/2
(no trailing slash)

I know that maybe this is a very common issue, but all the examples I find online are.. "oversized" for this simple rule

So, how can I automatically add a trailing slash? Please notice that a rule like:

```
RewriteRule    ^contatti/$    contatti/?iModule=10    [L]
```

adds automatically a slash...
And I tried also:

```
RewriteRule  ^concorso/(.*)/?$    concorso/?iModule=13&iData=$1   [L]
```

(last slash optional) but I get Apache errors:

```
[Wed Dec 29 10:02:41 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2010:10:02:41 +0100] "GET /concorso/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 535
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error is because you run into a loop when you rewrite your URL in a way, that the rewritten URL also matches your rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restricting the characters that the pattern will accept to prevent your pattern from matching what you are rewriting to.  For example, if you only want to match urls `/concorso/###` where ### are digits:

```
RewriteRule  ^concorso/([0-9]+)/?$    concorso/?iModule=13&iData=$1   [L]
```

More generally, this will work by only matching URLs without query strings:

```
RewriteRule  ^concorso/([^?]*)/?$    concorso/?iModule=13&iData=$1   [L]
```

Comment: Thanks cdhowie, the first works perfectly and I also enhanced rule with this, to include some text: RewriteRule  ^concorso/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$  concorso/?iModule=13&iData=$2 [NC,L] The second example still throws me an error